# Need sample login code for oauth-v2 by using only box.net jars

Tags: android, box-api

I am trying to integrate box.net in my android app for cloud access. I have included only boxandroidlibraryv2.jar and BoxJavaLibraryV2.jar(taken by building the source code in eclipse) and not included source code in https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk-v2). . I need sample code to authenticate the user only by using these jars. Can anyone share the sample source code.

Comment: Hello, Can you give me the link from where you downloaded the jar files?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to authenticate is to use the OAuthActivity, which is included in the SDK. Add it to your manifest to use it.

```
// If you don't have a server redirect url, use this instead:
// Intent intent = createOAuthActivityIntent(context, clientId, clientSecret, false, "http://localhost"); 
Intent intent = OAuthActivity.createOAuthActivityIntent(this, clientId, 
    clientSecret);
startActivityForResult(intent);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Get the error message for why authentication failed.
        String failMessage = data.getStringExtra(OAuthActivity.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        // Implement your own logic to handle the error.
       handleFail(failMessage);
    } else {
        // You will get an authenticated oath token object back upon success.
        BoxAndroidOAuthData oauth = data.getParcelableExtra(OAuthActivity.BOX_CLIENT_OAUTH);
                // If you don't want to supply a customized hub or parser, use null to fall back to defaults.
                BoxAndroidClient client = new BoxAndroidClient(clientId, clientSecret, null, null, null);
                client.authenticate(oauth);
        youOwnMethod(client);
    }
}
```

Our sdk auto refreshes OAuth access token when it expires. You will want to listen to the refresh events and update your stored token after refreshing.

```
boxClient.addOAuthRefreshListener(OAuthRefreshListener listener) {
    new OAuthRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(IAuthData newAuthData) {
        BoxOAuthToken oauthObject = boxClient.getAuthData();
            // TODO: save the auth data.
        }                              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already fixed this issue due the long time that this question has been made. But just to be more precise on it (i found myself in a very similar issue).

You cannot use boxandroidlibraryv2.jar in your project since this has some resources (used to make the authentiation asking user/pwd).